# Weighted sum of large numbers

Tags: real-analysis, probability

From the law of large numbers, if $X_1,X_2,...X_N$ are i.i.d random variable, then we have
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} (\Sigma_1^N X_i)=\mu$$
where $\mu$ is the mean of $X_i$.

What I want to ask is if there is a infinite sequence $a_i$.
Can we express the value of $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} (\Sigma_1^N a_iX_i)$ with $a_i$?

Comment: Do you know anything about the sequence $a_i$? In general, this will have the same bad behavior as nonconvergent series can have (the $1/N$ smoothing will [help some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), but not in all cases).

Comment: @MarioCarneiro everything about $a_i$ is known. Actually, $a_i$ is a given sequence. And I don't care whether this sum is convergent or not. I want to know whether this sum can be expressed by $a_i$ and the mean of X

Comment: What I mean is that you need to place additional restrictions on what sequences you are willing to consider. At minimum, if $a_i$ is not Cesaro-summable then the limit will not exist (as a finite number), unless all $X_i=0$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Just as I said, for example, if the sum is equal to $\Sigma a_i$, even this sum is not convergent with N. It's OK.

Comment: In the case of equal weights, we have the limit equal to a specific number, namely $\mu$, *almost surely*, but in the case of different weights there is no chance of a similar result, because you could just set $a_i=0$ for co-finitely many $i$ to get nonzero variance. However, it seems likely that you could prove that $E[\lim\bar X_i]=\mu\lim\frac1N\sum_1^N a_n$ if $a_n$ converges.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro That is what I want to prove. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result regarding the expectation is actually quite simple:

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}E[\frac1N\sum_1^Na_nX_n]=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_1^Na_n\mu=\mu\bar a,$$

where $\bar a=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_1^Na_n$, assuming this limit exists. However, it doesn't come with as much force as the real law of large numbers, because it doesn't say anything about the variance. For that, we can use the following extension to LLN known as Kolmogorov's strong law and mentioned at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers):

> If $X_n$ are independent (not necessarily i.i.d.), then $\bar X_n-E[\bar X_n]\overset{a.s.}{\to}0$, provided that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\operatorname{Var}[X_k]<\infty$.

From this, assuming that $\operatorname{Var}[X_i]=\sigma^2$ is finite, if we set $X_n\mapsto a_nX_n$ in this law we get

$$P\left(\lim_N\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^Na_n(X_n-\mu)=0\right)=1$$
$$P\left(\lim_N\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^Na_nX_n-\mu\bar a=0\right)=1$$
$$P\left(\lim_N\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^Na_nX_n=\mu\bar a\right)=1$$

so $\lim_N\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^Na_nX_n\overset{a.s.}{\to}\mu\bar a$, provided that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k^2}{k^2}<\infty$.

---

Regarding the distribution of the infinite sum $\sum_na_nX_n$, it satisfies no law of large numbers analogue, because there is no smoothing factor. The variance only gets worse after you add each term. So it won't converge almost surely to anything unless the distribution of $X_i$ is trivial (concentrated at one point). However, it will be true that the expectation is $E[\sum_na_nX_n]=\mu\sum_na_n$ and the variance is $\operatorname{Var}[\sum_na_nX_n]=\sigma^2\sum_na_n^2$, assuming these are finite.

Comment: Can we also conclude that 
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \Sigma a_iX_i \overset{a.s.}{\to} \mu \Sigma a_i$$

Comment: No, because of the reasons I mentioned earlier. I added an addendum to the answer to cover this case.

Comment: What if for any $n$ I have that $\sum_n a_n = 1$ , i.e. as I add more terms to the sum, $a_n$'s change in such a way that each $a_n \to 0$ and their sum is still $1$?  Does this allow for $\sum_n a_n X_n$ to converge? The "vanilla" SLLN has $a_n = 1/n$, but I am looking at the situation where $a_n$'s are not the same.  Thank you

Comment: PS  We can re-state the problem from my previous comment as follows: define $W_n = \sum_n w_n$ with $w_n>0$, and $S_n = \sum_n w_n X_n / W_n$ where $X_n$ are i.i.d. What are the conditions for $S_n$ to converge almost surely and what does it converge to?  Thank you

Comment: PPS  I guess we might need another condition and that is $W_n \to \infty$ which we can assume here too.  Thank you

Comment: @Confounded I'd be very interested to know if you found an answer to your last question.

Comment: @Skywear  Hi. Unfortunately, I did not find any formal proof for LLN of a weighted sum, but since each $w_i >0$ it can be shown that the variance of $S_n$ is of order $1/n$ and hence goes to $0$ with $n -> \infty$, while the expectation of $S_n$ is equal to $E[X_i]=\mu$.